# how to scroll down with scrollview in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, scrollview

hi i am bigginer in kivy and i want to scroll down a gridlayout in kivy. when i set the size_hint_y to 1.01 it make a scrollview top of my gridlayout and my gridlayout go down

this is my kv code:

```
<layout_>:
id:layout

GridLayout:

    ScrollView:
        size:300,500                
        pos: 0 , 0
        do_scroll_y:True
        do_scroll_x:False
        size_hint:(None, None)

        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0
            heigth:self.minimum_height

            
            GridLayout:
                size_hint_y:0
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1 , 1 , 1 , .5
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        pos:5, -210
                        size: 290 , 100 
            GridLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba:1,1,1,.5
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        pos:5,-470
                        size:290,250     

            GridLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color: 
                        rgba:1,1,1,.5
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        pos:5,-580
                        size:290,100 
            GridLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color: 
                        rgba:1,1,1,.5
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        pos:5,-690
                        size:290,100                   
            GridLayout:
                spacing:"0dp"
                padding:"0dp"


             #--temp and conty label--# 
                Label:               
                    text:"13\n yourcounty"
                    pos:190 , -90 
                    font_size: 30

                Label:
                    text:"fells like"
                    pos:200 , -130
                    font_size: 8                  
            ScrollView:
                size:290,100                 
                pos: 5 , -210
                do_scroll_x:True
                do_scroll_y:False
                GridLayout:
                    id:set_and_rise_grid
                    size_hint_x: 6.02
                    height:self.minimum_height
                    width:self.minimum_width
```

when i set size_hint_y:0 of my gridlayout its true but it cant scroll and when i set it to 1.01 it will go to top of my gridlayout

i tried scroll_y:0.5 but it didnt work

Comment: There's a huge amount of code here. Can you reduce it to the minimum which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: hello @HughW thanks for your advice i did it. I would be grateful if you would answer my question.